# ASP.NET MVC Framework 'REST-like' API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, restful-authentication

I have developed a 'REST-like' XML API that I wish to expose for consumption by third-party web applications. I'm now looking to implement a security model for the exchange of data between a third-party application and the 'REST-like' XML API. I would appreciate suggestions for a suitable asymmetric encryption model.

Comment: What's wrong with HTTPS / SSL? Or is the "REST-like" not HTTP at all?

Comment: Why the non-descriptive title?

Comment: @jonelf - nothing wrong with https/ssl - I wanted stackoverflow's opinion before I get down to work. thanks :)

Comment: @Justice - sorry, forgive my english skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want encryption why not just use SSL to encrypt the connection rather than encrypting the response data?  If 128-bit SSL isn't sufficient, then you'll either need to integrate some existing PKI infrastructure using an external, trusted authority or develop a key distribution/sharing infrastructure yourself and issue your public key and a suitable private key/identifier to your API consumers.  Choose one of the cryptography providers in System.Security.Cryptography that supports public/private key exchange.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS works with asymmetric key encryption. It is well-known protocol easy to implement. 
It protects against 3p intrusion in your communication.

All you need to implement "below" is authentication - to make sure your user known to you.

Common thing to do is to provide users with key that needs to be sent with every request.

Answer (score 0):

Most common is to implement the OAuth protocol. This is what is used for the OpenSocial providers that checks authorization with 2-legged and/or 3-legged oAuth

Just do some google search and you will find a lot of implementations.